# Simple RecyclerView with ImageView scroll lagging

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple `MainActivity` with only 1 `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`.
Dataset is fixed at 8 items. Each row is a single `ImageView` like this `item.xml`:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Here is my adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(private val drawableResIds: List<Int>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    class MyViewHolder(val imageView: ImageView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(imageView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(rootView as ImageView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // #1: lagging
        // holder.imageView.setImageResource(drawableResIds[position])

        // #2: lagging
        // holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(
        // ContextCompat.getDrawable(holder.imageView.context, drawableResIds[position])
        // )

        // #3: lagging
        // holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(
        // BitmapFactory.decodeResource(holder.imageView.context.resources, drawableResIds[position])
        // )

        // #4: smooth
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.context)
            .load(drawableResIds[position])
            .into(holder.imageView);
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = drawableResIds.size
}
```

**Problem:** The recycler view scrolling is lagging.

**What I tried:** I already set `setHasFixedSize(true)` and `setItemViewCacheSize(20)`.
You can see I tried 4 approaches to set image. But only with Glide, the scrolling is smooth.

**Question:** Why is it lagging? And what is the correct way to set an image for smooth scrolling?
(I expected a simple method, avoid fancy caching or use lib)

Also, the set image operations only happen once, since the "list's slots" are big enough, don't need to re-bind while scrolling I guess. So is it an issue with the Android rendering image? The images are JPEG 800x400 (size on disk 70-200Kb)

Demo source code can be found here: https://github.com/akivamu/rv-demo

**UPDATE 1:** I replaced `RecyclerView` with `ScrollView` + 8 static `ImageView`, the phenomenon is the same

**UPDATE 2:** I move those images from `drawable` -> `drawable-xxxhdpi`. And it's scrolling smoothly!!! Not sure if will work on other density devices

Comment: This is what I did in my current project and it is not lagging. https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#load-bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I move the images used in `RecyclerView` from folder `drawable` -> `drawable-xxxhdpi`.
And it's scrolling smoothly on my device (guess it's xxxhdpi device)

Not sure if will work on other density devices (other than xxxhdpi)

Still don't know the reason behind, should ask in another question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your image resolutions. Each pixel is stored in 4 bytes of memory (red, green, blue, alpha) so for a 800×400 image it will consume ~1.22MB of RAM. While your image view dimensions is much less than your image resolutions. In this cases you need to resize your image to fit the view dimensions before setting it on the view to avoid large memory consumptions or else drawing your views will take more than 16ms and results to laggy scrolls. Using libraries like Glide will just save you the time and effort of resizing or caching images on your own.

Comment: What do you mean the ImageView dimensions is much less? I think it's much bigger. Also, don't think 8 x 1.22MB is that big mem consumption

Comment: I mean image view width and height. 1.22MB for a single image is considered a large amount of memory footprint. A view should only consume memory as much as its dimensions otherwise it will result to longer `onDraw` calls. You should also consider images cached in memory. Lots of images consume a significant amount of memory while using memory cache which is not your problem cause you have only 8 images, but as you saw the `onDraw` calls took more time just because of the dimensions difference between images and image view.

Answer (score 0):

I've never experienced this before, I think it's lag because the image is large.but I usually resize the bitmap to ImageView size, then recycle the original bitmap instead of using 800x600 image to the ImageView.

```
ImageView iconView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_poster);
iconView.post(() -> {
  final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/your/image/path");
  if (bitmap == null)
    return;
  final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  matrix.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, iconView.getWidth(), iconView.getHeight()), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
  final Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
  bitmap.recycle();
  iconView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
});
```

I'm not sure this will work in your case, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Loading static image from `drawable` folder is a heavy task. Whatever code you write in `onBindViewHolder()` will be executed whenever an item is displayed. It means that `holder.imageView.setImageResource(drawableResIds[position])` will be called repeatedly for each item when you scroll the list. Therefor, if you are sure that you have just 8 images and no more, check memory available and load the 8 images and save in an array first. Beside, resize images if need, it's meaningless when show a big size image as a thumbnail,...Also, Bitmap rendering affects android performance, refer caching mechanism too https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap

Comment: Bind ViewHolder operations are only called in first few full scrolling. After that, I guess the list already has 8 ViewHolders, no need to bind again, so binding won't be called again. Caching is not neccessary, here is only 8 images (800x400)

Comment: Anyway, I tried preloading all images and use setImageDrawable, still the same

Comment: @Akivamu, No, the `onCreateViewHolder` called 8 times, the `onBindViewHolder` called multiple times when you scrool the list, just put a log command and you will see that.

Comment: I did. If you have enough  bound ViewHolder for whole dataset, won't need to bind anymore. I use `setItemViewCacheSize()`